# Delete all files in Azure Storage on a schedule

Tags: azure-storage, azure-powershell

I have an Azure file share with a temp folder. I was programmatically deleting the files however I now believe a better approach is to decouple the app from this task and delete the files using powershell or Azure CLI or azure functions or Azure Automation.  [Remove-AzureStorageFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/remove-azurestoragefile?view=azurermps-6.13.0) seems to be what I need.  But I'm not sure how to use it to delete all files in a folder and to have it operate hourly.
I'd prefer to delete all the files rather than delete the folder if possible.

I came up with this answer after help from kamran
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a simple solution you can use Azure logic app. List the items, loop through and delete one by one. Something like this:
[image]

**Update:**
Now that you are using File share you need to do it like this:
What is happening here is we are checking if we have folder then do a loop over that folder.
[image]

Comment: This looks great - However, I am stuck on the list files.  It won't let me list files in the sub folder.

Comment: Did you select Flat listing?

Comment: I was using file Storage instead of blob storage - there is no option for flat listing

Comment: Wow - I appreciate your answer.  I got a result in the end - I've updated my question to include my version.  I will however also try yours.

Comment: cool. If you have only one folder then just set the path as you mentioned but if you have multiple folders along with some files in the root then you need 2 loops. Cheers.